# org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Still need to wire in composite in-memory value generation

Tags: java, hibernate

Следуя [туториалу](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/topical/html_single/generated/GeneratedValues.html) пытаюсь сделать in-memory генератор полного имени (имя + фамилия + отчество). Вот что я написал:

```
@Entity
public class User extends AuditEntity {
    ...
    private Name name;
    ...
    // геттеры, сеттеры
}

@Embeddable
public class Name {

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private final String first;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private final String last;

    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private final String middle;

    @GeneratorType(type = FullNameGenerator2.class, when = GenerationTime.INSERT)
    private String fullName;

    // геттеры, сеттеры
}

public class FullNameGenerator2 implements ValueGenerator<String> {

    @Override
    public String generateValue(Session session, Object obj) {
        return "full name (generated)";
    }

}
```

При запуске приложения выдает ошибку:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Still need to wire in composite in-memory value generation

Подозреваю, что ошибка из-за того, что я не указал Hibernate-у о своем генераторе FullNameGenerator2.

Comment: Аннотация `@GeneratorType` не работает для `@Embeddable`, для сущности все работает корректно